# Why does "wrap_content" doesn't work for any ...Layout in XML file using support.design.widgets?

Tags: android, xml

I am here for the first time and i have a question.
I have this XMl file in my android project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_schedule"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/mainBackground"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


      <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_schedule"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_schedule"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But when i want to add any Layouts, for example LinearLayout, in CoordinatorLayour after AppBarLayout(with atribute layout_height = "wrap_content"), i see, that it places at the begining of the DrawerLayout. I really cannt understand why this is so. What's wrong with my XML? Or need i to add iany Layouts programmly?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. What is happening? What do you expect to happen? When you say it "places at the beginning" do you mean that the top of the LinearLayout is at the top of the screen?

Comment: Yes, it is on top, but i need my Layout to attach to AppBarLayout. But when i put my Layout in code after "AppBarLayout" code section, it appears on top. Maybe my question wass incorrect, cause of my English, so i think now my question is "How can attach any Layout to AppBarLayout using my XML file?" I need something like this: NavigationView is hidden, Bar is on top (these two are done) and Layout which attached to the bottom of Tab.

Comment: You should put the XML you are having a problem with in your question to make it clearer. You have said you're having a problem when you add the LinearLayout, but your code doesn't show the LinearLayout so that makes it more difficult for anyone to help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem here in the `height` of `AppBarLayout`.

Try to set it's height to some value in `dp`, i.e. `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"` or just `android:layout_height="50dp"`